# ActiveMQ migration to another server wiath save version

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have activemq which has a huge *storeUsage ~100GB*, sice it was about to exhaust I cnaged to value of storeUsage and triying to restart again but not activemq server is not staring.

What can be issue, nothing more in log in debug mode
Can I just backup kahaDb and delete all file inside kahaDb and restart it ?

Please suggest what to do, Its prod server and we have big issue.

---

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: If the broker won't start it generally always tells you why, search the logs

Comment: I searched that, but there was nothing, but it could be that it is taking time as data is huge, may be it will start in some hour, I waited for 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete kahaDB the contents of your queues and topics will be gone. If you do not care about them - delete it. It will most likely render your broker usable again.

You should have tried to get rid of old messages in the first place. They use a lot of resources. A message broker is not a database.

You could also try to restore your kahadb on a much more powerful machine.

I assume monitoring of your production environment was faulty or non-existent. So you should invest in that area, too.